# Handling OAUTH2 with a webhook

Tags: oauth-2.0, webhooks

I've never really used webhooks, but will have to in the near future due to some new accounting software we are bringing on and needing to integrate it with our CRM and project management software. All are online, by the way.

The biggest problem I can see right away is how to handle OAUTH2:

- The accounting software supports PUT and POST webhooks on create and update
- This information should be PUT or POST into our CRM system
- The CRM system requires an OAUTH 2.0 handshake, which I'm pretty sure webhooks do not support

So my questions are the following:

- Typically, webhooks do not support OAUTH 2.0, correct?
- Is this vendor specific or simply the way webhooks are?
- Do I have to write middleware that takes the webhook request, handles the authentication, and then passes the payload along to the intended endpoint?

The last point is what I'm thinking I need to, but just wanting to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, researching a lot more and talking to some other devs, apparently webhooks are just not that smart. You do have to build an API endpoint that would take the request from the app that triggered the webhook, send it to that endpoint, that endpoint would handle the authentication and then pass on the payload to the final end point.